# Windows 7 Installation Folder: x86, x64 and another info

Tags: windows-7, installation, iso-image, 64-bit, x86

I've downloaded a lot of Windows 7 versions (release candidates, trial, x64 and x86, etc). The bad part is that the downloaded iso files don't have clear names, so I cannot to know wich version is each file.

I can check the files inside the iso using 7-Zip, by example. Then, reading the files and folders in the installation disk, how can I tell what Windows version and platform the installation refers to?

Comment: Could you clarify this question a bit so it doesn't look so much like piracy?

Comment: davr: What the point? I've got a lot of Windows 7 RC and trial versions (7100, 7022, etc...). My Windows 7 is original and I've not problems with piracy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit:

I actually just found [this tool](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090706/windows-7-iso-verifier/), the Windows 7 ISO verifier. It has records of the hashes of various releases of Windows 7 ISOs. It is not updated any more, but if the ISOs are a bit older it will help:

[image]

another method, not the best solution, is to hash the ISO files using [MD5](http://www.md5summer.org/) for example, then put that hash into a search engine. A number of sites post information regarding releases and will probably have the hash posted for verification.

I have just hashed my Windows 7 ISO and [searching its hash](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&source=hp&q=d8f675aaeb48057452666b0cd686d7f5&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=d8f675aaeb48057452666b0cd686d7f5&fp=49dee19d856e0faa) gave me the [correct result](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=6230792&postcount=365).

[image]

In this case, English 32-bit Windows 7 professional.